# Flux through the boundary of a rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

given the rectangle described by:

$0\leq x \leq 6$, $0 \leq y \leq 2$

And a fluid following the vector field:

$F = \langle x^3+2, y \cos(6x) \rangle$

We get the 2D curl:

$curl(F) = -6y\sin(6x)-0=-6y\sin(6x)$

By green's theorem, the flux through the boundary is thus:

$\int^6_0\int^2_0 -6y\sin(6x) dydx = -4\sin^2(18)$ (by wolfram, manually I got $-2\cos(36)$)

Neither of these answers is correct and I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: $\int \cos(6x) dx = \frac{1}{6} \sin(6x) + C$

Comment: I believe the flux is related to the divergence, not the curl

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if in six years nobody has been able to evaluate $\int_0^6\int_0^2{\rm div}\, F\,dy\,dx=\int_0^6\int_0^2 3x^2+\cos(6x)\,dy\,dx$ then I don't know what answer is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is arising from the fact that the double integral you are being led to calculate (i.e. the double integral of the curl) gives the counterclockwise *circulation* of the field around the boundary of this region.

To calculate the *flux* one calcuates the double integral of the *divergence* over the region.  So,

\begin{align}
\text (flux) = \Phi =\iint_R \nabla \cdot \text{F dA} 
&= \int^6_0\int^2_0 3x^2+\cos(6x) dydx \\
&= 2 \int^6_0 3x^2+\cos(6x) dx \\
&= 2 \left[ x^3 +\frac{1}{6}\sin(6x)\right]^6_0 \\
&= 2 \left[ 6^3 +\frac{1}{6}\sin(36)\right] \\
&= \color{blue}{\left[ 432 +\frac{1}{3}\sin(36)\right]}
\end{align}

See [this page](https://grimstad.uia.no/perhh/phh/fag/matem/MA209_eng/f/VectorCalculus/062.htm) for the two forms of Green's Theorem in 2D.  Note the first equation gives $\Phi$, the flux, while the second gives $C$, the circulation.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\int^6_0\int^2_0 -6y\sin(6x) dydx 
&= \int^6_0\sin(6x)dx\int^2_0 -6y dy \\
&= \dfrac{-\cos6x}{6}\Big|^6_0\dfrac{-6y^2}{2}\Big|^2_0 \\
&= \dfrac{1-\cos36}{6}\dfrac{-24}{2} \\
&= \color{blue}{-4\sin^218}
\end{align}

Comment: Which is not the correct answer as I said

Comment: The integral gives this answer, so your fault comes from other part!

Comment: Hence why I described the entire problem and then gave my solution, so that people could identify what error I made

Comment: I thought you want to verify the integral answer. Anyway I will check your solution. How did you find it with wolfram?

Comment: To simplify my query, I need the answer (and know how to get the answer) to the problem:

Find the flux of $F=\langle x^3+2, ycos(6x) \rangle$ through the boundary of the rectangle $0 \leq x \leq 6$; $0 \leq 2 \leq 2$

Answer (score -1):

I attempted to solve this.

$\frac{\partial F1}{\partial y}=0\ \ \ \frac{\partial F2}{\partial x}=-6ysin(6x)$

$\int^6_0 \int^0_2 -6ysin(6x)  \ dydx $

$\int^6_0 -6ysin(6x) \ dx ]^2_0 = \int^6_0 -12sin(6x) \ dx$

$\frac{12}{6}cos(6x)]^6_0 = 2[cos(36)-1]$

Which is basically the same answer. What is the answer you are trying to attain?